# Proving 2nd ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

If $x=e^t$, can someone give me proof that 
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{e^{2t}}\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}−\frac{d}{dt}\right).
$$ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}
 = \frac{d}{dt} \times \frac{dt}{dx}
 = \frac{d/dt}{dx/dt}
 = e^{-t} \frac{d}{dt}.
$$

Note that
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{d}{dx} \right]
$$
and you can now use the previous result.